# Imprimir quantidade de nós em uma lista

Tags: c, algoritmo, while

Esse código abaixo não funciona corretamente, eu digito 5 nós e era pra me retornar o número 5 (quantidade total de nós inseridos). Acontece que me retorna 4.

```
int qtd_no_lista (tipo_lista * recebida)
{
 tipo_lista * aux = recebida;
 int cont=0;
  while (aux -> prox != NULL)
  {
    aux = aux ->prox;
    cont++;
  }
 printf("A quantidade de nos presente na lista e %d\n",cont);
 return cont;
}
```

Eu acho que o erro está na linha do `while`, não tenho certeza.

Está decrementando, acho que quando aponto para o próximo ele automaticamente decrementa no total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que somar um manualmente se manter esta lógica. Ou pode só começar do 1 que é mais simples.

O problema é que o último item da lista tem como valor de `prox` exatamente o valor `NULL`, portanto o laço vai parar nele, ele não será avaliado, então não será contado.

E considerado a pergunta anterior eu faria isto com `for`, eliminaria pelo menos 4 linhas.

Comment: Então sempre vai ser assim: o prox vai ter como valor NULL? Falando desse código aí, porque isso tá errado. O laço para no NULL e não é contado no final?

Comment: Porque você está mandando fazer isto. Não tem nada de errado, é só matemática.

Comment: Consegui aqui retornar a quantidade correto, removi o '-> prox' e compilei retorno corretamente agora.

Comment: É uma solução, só tenho minhas dúvidas se sempre fará tudo o que deseja. Nem posso dizer porque eu não sei o que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Basta modificar

```
while (aux -> prox != NULL)
```

por

```
while (aux != NULL)
```

*Obs: O restante está correto, não mude o contador para iniciar em 1 porque retornará um valor errado caso você passe um lista vazia.